# Корни славянских и русских имен

Tags: ономастика, морфология

Выделяются ли корни и суффиксы в славянских именах типа: *Владимир, Вячеслав, Владислав и др.*, а также именах появившихся уже в XX веке - *Светлана, Владилен, Октябрина и др.* или в этих именах только один корень и окончание?

Comment: Сейчас идет тенденция, что даже в нарицательных словах не выделяются морфемы (как-то натолкнулся на разбор слова "задача", где корнем оказался "задач", представляете?), что уж говорить об именах. Я же считаю, что выделять необходимо, ибо так понимание языка в целом и значения слова в частности углубляются.

Comment: Проблемы с разбором слов типа "задача", действительно, существуют, здесь как-то не выражена единая точка зрения. Мне думается, что правильно было бы считать "задачу"  словом с непроизводной основой, образующим собственное словообразовательное гнездо. Однако в этой непроизводной основе следует выделять приставки и суффиксы, если в современном языке они участвуют в словообразовании:  за/да/ч/а. С именами та же история, например: непроизводная основа в слове Светлан/а, но при этом выделение морфем, составляющих  непроизводную основу: Свет/л/ан/а, сравнить: велик/ий - велик/ан.

Comment: С основой в слове "задача" проблем нет, она там "задач". Другое дело, что там и корневой морфемой называют "задач", хотя, на мой взгляд, совершенно очевидна цепочка "задача" <- "задать" <- "дать".

Comment: http://slovonline.ru/slovar_sostav/b-18/id-599821/svetlana.html
Здесь: за/да/ч/а, Свет/л/ан/а.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ "Культуры письменной речи":

Вопрос 804:    Насколько правильно разбирать имена собственные по составу? Можно ли выделить корни у этих слов (например, Михаил, Юрьевец, Москва и т. д.)?
Ответ:   Как и любые слова языка, имена собственные состоят из морфем, другое дело, что в них традиционно выделяются только корень (он равен основе) и окончание: Михаил[] - Михаил[а], Москв[а] - Москв[ы].

http://www.gramma.ru/ARRM/?RG1=6&flag=1&RG2=all&page=6

При образовании уменьшительных имен основа усекается: Светлан/а - Свет/а.

В именах выделяют только суффиксы субъективной оценки: Тан/я - Тан/ечк/а,  Маш/а - Маш/еньк/а, Саш/а - Саш/к/а,

Comment: Про уменьшительные имена это понятно, я как-то и сам на этот вопрос отвечал. Меня интересуют полные имена, где корень вполне себе можно выделить.

Владислав - влад-и-слав, где "и" - соединительная гласная, а "влад" и "слав" - корни.

Светлана - светл-ан-а - где "светл" - корень, "-ан" - суффикс, а "а" - окончание.

Владилен - влади-лен - аббревиатура от Владимир Ленин и т. п.